# Issue with key assignment to dynamic children in React-Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm creating a React app on Rails and have encountered a problem regarding key assignment to dynamic children.

Below is a pared-down copy of my code:

```
class Records extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var records = 
            this.props.data.map(function(record) {
                return <div>
                           <Record key={record.id} data={record} />
                        </div>;
            });
        return (
            <div>
                {records}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Record extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Title: {this.props.data.title}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The code runs correctly except for the warning below that appears on the console:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. 
Check the render method of `Records`.
```

I've followed the link contained within the warning to the React guide (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children).

Though I feel I've implemented their recommendation that the key should always be supplied directly to the components in the array, not to the container HTML child of each component in the array, I still receive this warning in the console.

Does anyone have any ideas why? I completely appreciate any help you might provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should add the key props to the outer div, not to your Record instance.

```
var records = 
            this.props.data.map(function(record) {
                return <div key={record.id}>
                           <Record data={record} />
                        </div>;
            });
```

In fact, you don't need the wrapping div at all.

The warning is there because you need to add the key prop to the repeated element, and in your code you have a list of divs, each containing a Record (not a list of Records). 
React asks you to do so to be able to "track" (identify) these divs which would be exactly the same without a way to identify them. React needs this ids to efficiently track DOM mutations (e.g. reordering them, removing them, etc)

Then, if you use ES6 (transpiled with Babel or similar) along with JSX you can just to this:

```
var records = this.props.data.map(record => <Record data={record} key={record.id} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, the child in the is the surrounding `<div>` element, not the `Record` component which has the `key` property.

Your resulting HTML structure looks like this

```
<div>
   <div><h1 key="1">...</h1></div>
   <div><h1 key="2">...</h1></div>
   <div><h1 key="3">...</h1></div>
</div>
```

So indeed React is correct, the collection does not have a unique key for the top-level element.

Your two options are:

(A) Add the `key` property to the surrounding `<div>` such that it looks like this

```
<div>
   <div key="1"><h1>...</h1></div>
   <div key="2"><h1>...</h1></div>
   <div key="3"><h1>...</h1></div>
</div>

var records = 
   this.props.data.map(function(record) { 
      return <div key={record.id}>
                <Record data={record} />
             </div>;
```

Or

(B) Get rid of the surrounding `<div>` altogether as it's not needed.

```
var records = 
    this.props.data.map(function(record) { 
       return <Record key={record.id} data={record} />;
```

*Side-note:* React expects your `render` call to only return a single top-level element, so you only need a container element if you want to have multiple sibling elements in a render call.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the issue.